# SupplicantState COMPLETED but DetailedState OBTAINING_IPADDR while actually connected to Wifi?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-wifi, wifimanager

I'm using API level 27 but run my app on a 6.0 tablet. Here is the suspicious code:

```
WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)pContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wi = wm.getConnectionInfo();
SupplicantState ss = wi.getSupplicantState();
NetworkInfo.DetailedState ds = wi.getDetailedStateOf( ss );
String ssid = wi.getSSID();
int ip = wi.getIpAddress();
```

My tablet is connected (I see "connected" in the WiFi panel) to an ad hoc network created on a laptop. There is no internet access.

`ss` is `COMPLETED`

`ds` is `OBTAINING_IPADDR`

`ip` is `-745953088` (192.168.137.211)

Why is the `DetailedState` set to `OBTAINING_IPADDR` rather than `CONNECTED`?

Answer (score 0):

Look into class **android.net.wifi.WifiInfo**

```
static {
    stateMap.put(SupplicantState.DISCONNECTED, DetailedState.DISCONNECTED);
    stateMap.put(SupplicantState.INTERFACE_DISABLED, DetailedState.DISCONNECTED);
    stateMap.put(SupplicantState.INACTIVE, DetailedState.IDLE);
    stateMap.put(SupplicantState.SCANNING, DetailedState.SCANNING);
    stateMap.put(SupplicantState.AUTHENTICATING, DetailedState.CONNECTING);
    stateMap.put(SupplicantState.ASSOCIATING, DetailedState.CONNECTING);
    stateMap.put(SupplicantState.ASSOCIATED, DetailedState.CONNECTING);
    stateMap.put(SupplicantState.FOUR_WAY_HANDSHAKE, DetailedState.AUTHENTICATING);
    stateMap.put(SupplicantState.GROUP_HANDSHAKE, DetailedState.AUTHENTICATING);
    stateMap.put(SupplicantState.COMPLETED, DetailedState.OBTAINING_IPADDR);
    stateMap.put(SupplicantState.DORMANT, DetailedState.DISCONNECTED);
    stateMap.put(SupplicantState.UNINITIALIZED, DetailedState.IDLE);
    stateMap.put(SupplicantState.INVALID, DetailedState.FAILED);
}
```

You can see that **DetailedState.CONNECTED** is not mapped with any SupplicantState value. Don't know why..

Use ***SupplicantState*** instead of DetailedState to check if the state is connected.